# C# runtime late binding on non correlated types

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, type-conversion, runtime

I've been asked to port a NetFramework/Ef6 assembly to NetCore / EFCore. The migration must be split into small chunks and spread over multiple deploys so it can be tested by QA over time.

My idea is to couple all of the logic to a shared type IContext and to return at runtime the EF6 context in the old assembly and the EFCore context in the NetCore assembly so the team can gradually migrate individual services (logic) to the new runtime with minimal effort.

Since there's no common ancestor between the two contexts I was hoping to allow my code to use late binding to call functions on the instances I dynamically resolve in each assembly:

```
TypeA a = new TypeA();

a = (dynamic) new TypeB();

a.Log();


public class TypeA
{
    public void Log()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TypeA");
    }
}

public class TypeB
{
    public void Log()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TypeB");
    }
}
```

This throws RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'TypeB' to 'TypeA'

Is there any solution to allow such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
dynamic a = new TypeA();
a = new TypeB();
a.Log();
```

If you plan to use multiple assembly load contexts
[this post](https://ricoerhard.net/en/Log/Type-conversions-with-ALCs) may help you.